# Is it possible to debug a PHP GD script?

Tags: php, graphics, gd

One way to debug a PHP script is with the `echo` command. Since the `header` must be the first command sent in case of GD script, how do I examine a variable before sending the `header` to the browser?

Comment: I think xdebug help you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to debug a PHP GD script is using [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php). All `ECHO` commands will be buffered and later flushed after sending the `header` to the browser.